# How to check multiple rows in the database

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have 2 columns, sizes and colors, and the content of the table went like this:

```
sizes  colors

large  red
large  green
small  green
```

If I wanted to retrieve a record which had `large` in `sizes` table and `green` in `colors` table I would do something like this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE sizes='large' and colors='green'";
```

But what if I wanted to retreive `large` ONLY if it had both `red` and `green` in the rows, as above?

Comment: On a side note this is bad db design. This should be 3 tables. One table for sizes. One table for colors and then a middle table with items.

Comment: if that doesn't work then try this, WHERE sizes='large' AND colors='green' OR colors='red'

Comment: Please redesign your design and optimize the relations of the tables. As mentioned above you need to decompose this into different tables.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to need to check 2 rows that match. A self join is probably the easiest way to do it:-

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable a
INNER JOIN SomeTable b
ON a.sizes = b.sizes
WHERE a.sizes = 'large'
AND a.colors = 'red'
AND b.colors = 'green'
```

Avoiding using a JOIN, but this only returns the size (do you have other columns that you want to return?):-

```
SELECT sizes, COUNT(DISTINCT colors) AS colour_count
FROM SomeTable
WHERE sizes = 'large'
AND colors IN ('red', 'green')
GROUP BY sizes
HAVING colour_count = 2
```

Comment: I think he does not want join tables

Comment: Without a JOIN it would be very messy. Could be done with a COUNT / HAVING, but that would mean just bringing back 'large' and a count of 2 which would appear pointless (if there were more columns then it could be meaningful, but then we would need to define whether the rows those columns came from were from the red or green rows). Could possibly be done with variables but that would be nasty.

Comment: The `IN` clause seems to be the way to go, considering OP's code. I had thought about that after.

Comment: COUNT / HAVING with the IN clause only makes sense if the OP just wants to keeo the size (and possibly an aggregate column of the colors, using GROUP_CONCAT), but loses any other info from the rows (unless it is common to both rows and so can also be put in the GROUP BY clause).